# User authentication (registration, login and logout) - free SDK for Angular?

Tags: angular, authentication, google-signin, open-source, free

I'm hoping someone can provide guidance about user **authentication** in **Angular**. I want to use an authentication service that offers an **SDK** to handle user authentication (registration, login and logout). Preferably, the authentication service should offer authentication through social platforms like Google or Facebook.

I have looked into Okta's auth0 but it is not free and open source (although I know it does have a free plan).
What is the best alternative (specifically for Angular) to Okta's auth0 that is **free** and open source? I am using **PHP** for my backend.

Comment: You're asking really for two things - a client library such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client) and a free service that will be the Auth server.  You can take a look at [Keycloak](https://keycloak.org) as that will match your budget and requirements but you'll need to host.